# How can I disable adobe reader to save the pdf file in downloads?

Tags: android, savechanges, adobe-reader

I am working with an android app that I am showing a pdf file in an external pdf-reader.
I have noticed that when I use adobe reader it saves the pdf file in the downloads folder in my phone every time I open the pdf.

Is there any flag or something to get around this problem so that the users downloads map not gonna fill up?

My code:

```
package com.example.sbny.activities;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.sbny.R;
import com.example.sbny.data.Coupon;
import com.example.sbny.data.Paper;
import com.example.sbny.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.sbny.database.tables.AdcDB;
import com.example.sbny.database.tables.CouponDB;
import com.example.sbny.utils.FileUtil;
import android.support.v4.content.*;
import com.example.sbny.utils.Logger;

public class LasSollefteabladet extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.las_sollefteabladet);




        AdcDB adcDb = new AdcDB(DatabaseHelper.getInstance().getReadableDatabase());
        Paper paper = adcDb.getPaper();
        File paperFile = FileUtil.getFile(paper.getUrl());
        Uri contentUri = null;
        try
        {
            contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.sbny.fileprovider", paperFile);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Logger.log("kan inte dela filen");
        }



        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(contentUri,"application/pdf");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

        try
        {
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(LasSollefteabladet.this, "NO Pdf Viewer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    }



    @Override
    protected void onRestart()
    {
        super.onRestart();
        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManadensSollefteablad.class);
        nextScreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(nextScreen);
        Logger.log("onRestart");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not hide application from suggestion pop up, because that intent-filter is defined in that particular application which is listed out in suggestion pop up.

Comment: Okey so there is no way to make adobe reader to not save the pdf in downloads in the phone?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change Android settings of default app used to open files. The only thing you can do is to direct users to change their default program for opening pdf files. I wouldn't realy too much on user inteligence though...
Wouldn't be easier to delete these downloaded maps?

Comment: I don´t think I can get access to the Adobe Reader map in my download folder from my app, or is there any way to do it?

Comment: I would consider writing my own pdf viewer and direct users to choose it as the default action for viewing pdf files.